# Redirection after authentication not working in Spring Security

Tags: spring, authentication, redirect, spring-security, java-11

I'm having trouble redirecting to a specific page after a successful authentication using Spring Security. I want to create a way for external users who come in with their own authentication and have limited permissions on the application. To manage their access I have the following code:

```java
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        externalSession = false;
        try {
            String appUrl = ConstantesAplicacion.PROTOCOL+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getLocalPort()+request.getContextPath();
            String user = null;
            String password = null;
            
            /**
                Code that extracts and processes other properties of the request
            **/
            
            if (correct_parameters) {

                DigitalizaAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = (DigitalizaAuthenticationProcessingFilter)NavigationUtilities.getJSFBean("paramAuthenticationProcessingFilter");
                SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler success = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
                
                if (clinicalHistoryService.existsHistory(null, null, cip)) {
                    if(DataUtilities.isNotEmpty(cip)) {
                            String aux = "/xhtml/web.xhtml";
                            auxParameters = "&fullName="+fullName+ "&username="+user+"&code="+cid+"&ExternalAccess=True&Profile="+profile+"&random="+Math.random()*100000;
                            if (episode != null && !"".equals(episode)){
                                auxParameters = auxParameters +"&episode="+episode;
                            }
                            success.setDefaultTargetUrl(aux);
                    }
                } else {
                    success.setDefaultTargetUrl("/xhtml/web2.xhtml?searchErrorExt=1");
                }

                if(!externalSession){
                    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(success);
                    response.sendRedirect(appUrl + "/j_spring_security_check?j_username="+user+"&j_password="+password+""+auxParameters);
                }else{
                    response.sendRedirect(appUrl + "/xhtml/web.xhtml");
                }
            } else {
                LOG.error("invalid ip");         
                throw new DigitalizaAppException(); 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DigitalizaAppException(e);
        } 
    }
```

In this code, I try to authenticate the user and then redirect to "/xhtml/web.xhtml". However, the redirection or the logging in with spring security does not seem to be working. After execution, I receive no errors, but the redirection does not occur, it just leaves me on the page where I am located.

To access I use /externalAccess?username=""&password=""&...

My spring security configuration in the applicationContext-security:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    
        <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />    
        
        <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" > 
            <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied"/>
        
            <intercept-url pattern="/xhtml/errors/**" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>  
            <intercept-url pattern="/index.xhtml" access="isAuthenticated()" /> 
            
            <custom-filter ref="paramAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>   
            <custom-filter ref="exceptionTranslationFilter" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" /> 
            
            <form-login login-page="/inicio.xhtml" default-target-url="/xhtml/search/searchHistory.xhtml" 
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password"
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"         
                authentication-failure-url="/inicio.xhtml?error_page=1"
            />
                
            <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/inicio.xhtml"/>   
            <csrf disabled="true"/>
            <headers>
                <frame-options
                policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
             </headers>
        </http>
        
        <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
                <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>
        
        <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="es.organization.proyecto.infrastructure.encryption.DIGEncryption"/>
        <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="es.organization.proyecto.infrastructure.security.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl"/>
        
        <beans:bean id="paramAuthenticationProcessingFilter"  class="es.organization.proyecto.infrastructure.security.impl.proyectoAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
            <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
            <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
                <beans:bean id="successHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
                    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/xhtml/web2.xhtml" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="AuthenticationFailureHandler">
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
                    <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/inicio.xhtml?error_page=1" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
        
        <!-- Automatically receives AuthenticationEvent messages -->
        <beans:bean id="loggerListener" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener" />
    
        <beans:bean id="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository"/>

        <beans:bean  id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="es.organization.proyecto.infrastructure.security.JsfLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
            <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/inicio.xhtml"/>
            <beans:property name="redirectStrategy" ref="jsfRedirectStrategy" />
        </beans:bean >

        <beans:bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/> <!-- Constructor -->
            <beans:property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="jsfAccessDeniedHandler"/>
        </beans:bean>
        
        <beans:bean id="jsfAccessDeniedHandler" class="es.organization.proyecto.infrastructure.security.JsfAccessDeniedHandler">
            <beans:property name="loginPath" value="/errors/accessDenied.xhtml" />
        </beans:bean>
        
        <!-- Bean for managing the security redirection strategy -->
        <beans:bean id="jsfRedirectStrategy" class="es.organization.proyecto.infrastructure.security.JsfRedirectStrategy"/>
</beans:beans>
```

I have to say this code was working on spring 3. Now, upon upgrading to spring 5 is when the redirection has started to give problems.

What I've tried so far:

1. I have checked that the "/xhtml/web.xhtml" path exists in my project and that the route is written correctly.
2. I have used step-by-step debugging to see what is happening during the authentication and redirection process. I found nothing suspicious.
3. I have checked my application's logs but found no relevant information there.
4. I have verified my Spring Security configurations and everything seems to be in order.

Could anyone provide some guidance on what I might be doing wrong, or suggestions on what else I should check?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That is not how an `AuthenticatioNSuccesHandler` should be used. You should be writing your own implementation of a `AuthenticationSuccesHandler` which does the redirect. Next to that what you have now is dangerous, the filter is a singleton what do you think happens when you have 100 concurrent requests?

Comment: I have tried creating a simple custom success handler, in which I simply receive the login data and redirect in the onAuthenticationSuccess method. However, I cannot get it to redirect, the request is processed but it never reaches the destination nor does it seem to try. Regarding the singleton, the project is old and I currently do not have the capacity to make that change but thank you very much for the recommendation.

Comment: You don't need to change the fact that it is a singleton, but your current implementation is just wrong actually it is even dangerous.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand there may be issues with the current implementation, but at this time, my main focus is resolving the redirection problem. As soon as I have the opportunity, I will take a closer look at how to enhance the code.

Comment: As stated you shouldn't be doing it like this in the first place, the redirect logic should be in the succeshandler not the filter. As stated this code is actually dangerous especially in a concurrent situation (and I doubt you only have 1 user at a time). So rip out all that logic, place it in a succeshandler to do the redirect. One thing to note is that you are apparently in a JSF environment which makes things more complicated/worse.

Comment: I have already tried creating a custom success handler and doing the redirection from there, but the problem persists and the redirection is not performed. I'm not sure if this is related to using JSF as you suggest.

Comment: Well JSF does complicate things. Another thing is how is this being called? Is it a regular request or a request made through AJAX/javascript. If it is the latter then a redirect won't work as it is javascript that is handling the page and not the browser.

Comment: This is a regular request, not made via AJAX/javascript. I'm aware that I need to put the redirection logic in the success handler, but even with that change, the redirection doesn't happen correctly.

Comment: Are you really sure it is a regular request? As you are using JSF it could be that that is turning it into an async request (the fact that the redirect isn't happening is an indication for that).

Comment: For testing purposes, I send a request via the URL, for example, to the route www.mywebsite.com/externalAccess?parameter1=""&parameter2... I understand that this is a regular request. I wasn't aware that JSF could be converting it to an asynchronous request. I will investigate further to confirm if this is the case. Do you have any suggestions on how to correctly handle redirects in case it turns out to be an asynchronous request? Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The redirect will still happen but it is handled by the javascript handler on the JSF side not the actual browser (as mentioned before).